# V.2.61 - AVI file getting grayscale renderings instead of color

Tags: rendering, color

This is a father's desperate call for help. 
My son is very much into YouTube, and is now at the beginning of his quest with two more friends to start their channel.

Apparently the first step is to have an "Intro". He has done his research, decided that Blender is the best alternative for a 3d intro (free and very capable), installed Blender, downloaded a Blender intro template (after having gone through hundreds of them), lightly edited the template to match his needs, played, rendered the animation to an AVI file - only to find out that on his Windows 10 PC he is experiencing the infamous "Blender output file not visible in explorer" problem.

I looked into it too, and it seems the only solution is a repair reinstall of Windows, which he does not want to do because of the possibility of messing other things up.

We checked all previous versions of Blender one by one, and found that 2.61 does not inhibit this problem (actually maybe even 2.63 is OK, I am mixing up version numbers now).

We loaded the template into Blender 2.61, made similar selections matching those we did in 2.78, but when we render the movie, all we get is a grayscale version with almost nothing discernible on the display.

Can you please give us some pointers to what to look into? I will appreciate any help very much, and please bear in mind that we know very little or almost nothing about the technology and terminology involved.

Many thanks in advance, Arifi Koseoglu

NEW NOTES:
Today we have continued looking into the problem. It seems that the problem can be traced back to the .blend file having been created with a new version of Blender, and so not properly behaving on the older version we opted for. We concluded this by opening the same file in v.2.76 and v.2.61 with same/corresponding settings on the configuration area. The output of 2.76 was what we expected to see. Can this be the case? 
As a band-aid solution (the workweek has started) currently I am in process of rendering the whole project on my PC (which does not inhibit the "file invisible in windows explorer problem") with v.2.76, and they will use this time until we find a solution for their PC.
But, if blender project files are always backward-compatible - then we are at square 1. 
I am also attaching a screenshot of the Blender window processing the file.
Best regards and many thanks again.
Arifi Koseoglu

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: On the output section there are 3 options for color BW RGB, RGBA and B&W. make sure you are rendering as RGB.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, please consider editing and making a succinct text and stating the issue clearly. Please add pictures that show the render settings, render eingine, material properties and other relevant information along with examples of the final render problem. It makes no sense to me that you want to re-install windows or fight with different versions of blender. Just render using a different codec that the computer can handle. (H264 or mpeg should be quite compatible).

Comment: Adding a screenshot of your settings and output will help.

Comment: Also never ever ever render directly from 3D model into a video file format. Always render separate frames to image file format (like PNG) and only then convert to a video separately. Try that  in the most recent version **2.78a** and see of the grayscale problem persists. If not it's a some codec or encoding problem

Comment: Dear cetagon, Duarte Farrajota Ramos and Leander,
Many thanks for your answers. Very much appreciated. I have edited the question to respond to your comments.